# How to use @json2csv/node transforms

Tags: javascript, node.js, json2csv

I am trying to follow this [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@json2csv/node#node-transform), below is my code.

```
const { createReadStream, createWriteStream } = require("fs");
const { Transform } = require("@json2csv/node");
const Stream = require("stream");

const input = createReadStream("testinput.csv", { encoding: "utf8" });
const output = createWriteStream(`testoutput.csv`, { encoding: "utf8" });
const parser = new Transform({ fields: ["Date_time", "ch1_data_P"] });
parser
.on("line", (line) => {
    console.log(line);
})
.on("header", (header) => {
    console.log(header);
})
.on("error", (err) => console.error(err));
input.pipe(parser).pipe(output);
```

The input.csv has content below, which is proper as far as I know

```
"Date_time","ch1_data_P"
"2023-06-08T00:00:00Z",42.1
"2023-06-09T00:00:00Z",41.3
"2023-06-10T00:00:00Z",43.234
```

However, when I run this code, I get the error:

```
Error: Data items should be objects or the "fields" option should be included
at tokenizer.onToken (D:\megha\Documents\Projects\Hydrometeo\access2postgres\node_modules\@json2csv\plainjs\dist\cjs\StreamParser.js:74:30)
at Tokenizer.write (D:\megha\Documents\Projects\Hydrometeo\access2postgres\node_modules\@streamparser\json\dist\cjs\tokenizer.js:245:34)
at JSON2CSVStreamParser.write (D:\megha\Documents\Projects\Hydrometeo\access2postgres\node_modules\@json2csv\plainjs\dist\cjs\StreamParser.js:91:24)
at JSON2CSVNodeTransform._transform (D:\megha\Documents\Projects\Hydrometeo\access2postgres\node_modules\@json2csv\node\dist\cjs\Transform.js:33:31)
at Transform._write (node:internal/streams/transform:175:8)
at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)
at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10)
at ReadStream.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:766:22)
at ReadStream.emit (node:events:513:28)
```

I couldn't find any example in the doc with the fields, so I gave it my best try. There is also no information on the content of the input file in the docs.

How do I output a csv file? Eventually, I want to output a csv file from a json array of objects in memory, but I need to get the basic example working first.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the error you're getting is due to a misunderstanding of the packages you're using. @json2csv/node package is not for reading existing he CSV data, but for converting JSON data to CSV. This is why the error message says "Data item must be an object", indicating that you want his JSON object instead of the CSV row.

so, I write an example for you:

```
const { createWriteStream } = require("fs");
const { Transform } = require("@json2csv/node");

let data = [
  {
    "Date_time": "2023-06-08T00:00:00Z",
    "ch1_data_P": 42.1
  },
  {
    "Date_time": "2023-06-09T00:00:00Z",
    "ch1_data_P": 41.3
  },
  {
    "Date_time": "2023-06-10T00:00:00Z",
    "ch1_data_P": 43.234
  }
];

const json2csv = new Transform({
  fields: ["Date_time", "ch1_data_P"],
});

const output = createWriteStream("testoutput.csv", { encoding: "utf8" });

json2csv.pipe(output);

data.forEach((item) => {
  output.write(`${item.Date_time},${item.ch1_data_P}\n`);
});


json2csv.end();
```

Comment: When I run your code I get TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Object I also tried to stringify the object first, but then I get an Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end

Comment: @Melodie, sorry，I made a mistake, so I update the code, you can try again

Comment: Thank you but... what's the point of the library, if I have to output the csv myself? It's missing string quotes, by the way, which is why I want to use a library that will deal with this for me. How do I use the library to output csv? The description certainly says it can but the doc doesn't help to figure out how to.

Comment: @Melodie，The example above already outputs the JSON to a CSV file. I'm not sure what exactly you want to do? Can you give us more details so I can better support you?

Comment: Your example above outputs improper csv (missing string quotes). I would like to use the LIBRARY json2csv to produce the csv, and I can't find how to in the doc, where the examples are often borked like the one in my original post.